# Редирект с http на https в тот же адрес

Tags: .htaccess, apache, redirect

У меня в htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Если перейти по ссылке http://site.ru/link/script.php
то перекинет в https://site.ru/link/ а мне нужно чтобы редиректило с сохранением полного URL в моём примере это 
https://site.ru/link/script.php

Как написать условие в htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```